# how to set limitation in EntityManager (JPA) L1 or L2 cache size

Tags: orm, jpa, caching, second-level-cache, entitymanager

How to set L1 or L2 cache size-limitation. I concern of increasing the cache-size.
One way is defining timeout for cache but i want to know is it possible to make a constraint for cache size or not?

RGDS
Navid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to set L1 cache size-limitation

You can't. The only option is to [`clear`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#clear%28%29) the persistence context manually at regular intervals if you want to "control" (actually, [`clear`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#clear%28%29) is very aggressive, it removes **all entities**) its size.

> How to set L2 cache size-limitation

This depends on the underlying cache provider. In other words, this is done by configuring the L2 cache implementation. For example, EHCache has a [`maxElementInMemory`](http://ehcache.org/documentation/hibernate.html#Configuring_ehcache.xml) parameter.

---

> what happens in L1?! how much entities will be in the memory as time pass? w/o any constrains ?!

As much as you put in it, until an eventual [`OutOfMemoryError`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html), hence the need to `clear` explicitly:

- on large batch jobs (even if they occur in a single transaction)
- if a long-lived `EntityManager` is used

But the usual pattern is to use a short-lived `EntityManager` and most use cases are not batch jobs so this is not a concern.

#### See also

- JPA wiki book

  - [2.5 Clear](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Persisting#Clear)

Comment: what happens in L1?! how much entities will be in the memory as time pass? w/o any constrains ?!

Comment: You mean it is not my responsible to clear the L1 or L2 cache. isn't it? and caches will be removed automatically?

Comment: I mean that the L1 cache is per EntityManager which is typically a short-lived object. So unless you're doing batch jobs or unless you're using a long-lived EntityManager, you don't have to worry.